# How do I achieve the following layout?

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

In my Android app, I have an activity which has the following components wrapped in a `ConstraintLayout` (all `width=match_parent`, `height=wrap_content`):

```
title
scrollview
  linearLayout
    fragment1
    fragment2
    fragment3
    fragment4
adUnit
```

I want title and adUnit to stay fixed in place, and the remainder to scroll vertically. I've more or less got that happening, but the fragments are no longer showing all their content - I think they've all been set to the same height. How do I achieve what I want here?

Here's my current layout (stripped down to just the relevant parts):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_title">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_1"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_2" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_2"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_3" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_3"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_4" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        layout="@layout/layout_ad_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I would start with posting your current layout file so more people could answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, I've added that in now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create this type of layout. Check below xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="Title" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize=""
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the above layout title toolbar and adView fix at top and bottom. Replace your fragment with the help of **FrameLayout** and also you have the fragment through java class. For this check sample java code.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new Fragment1()); //Fragment2(),Fragment3(),Fragment4() 
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The frame layout is making all my fragments display on top of each other though, like they're all anchored to the top.  How do I deal with that?